# I was trying to delete the odd character from strings (please check my program below) I am getting one Exception

Tags: java, char, string-length, stringbuffer

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.*;

 public class Tester { 

 public static void main(String a[])    {

         String s;

         int len;
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

          s=sc.nextLine();

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(s);

        int i= 1;

        len= sb.length();

        len=len-1;

       while(i<=len)
      {
     sb.deleteCharAt(i);

       i=i+2; 
           }   
      System.out.println(sb);

     }

 }
```

i/p:

> abcdefghi

O/P:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 7  at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:824)
>     at java.lang.StringBuffer.deleteCharAt(StringBuffer.java:441)   at
>   Tester.main(Tester.java:29)

Comment: You are trying to delete a character at an index that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

It's because each time you delete a character the length of the String reduces by 1 and you are still iterating till the original length. Apply below change in your code so that value of `i` does not go beyond the `String`'s current length and `while` condition satisfies till valid length:

```
while(i<=len)
{
  sb.deleteCharAt(i);
  i=i+2; 
  len--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is every time deleteCharAt is called, it will deduct the sb length by one, so at some point i=7 but sb length is 5 and we are deleting the index at i=7, which results in the index out of bound exception you are seeing.
you can reduce length by 1 to fix this in your loop. len=len-1